# How would this program look in terms of drawing threading on a graph?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

In my attempt to understand `async`-`await`, I've written a simple program

```
private static async Task<int> GetIntAsync()
{
    Task<int> getInt = GetInt();
    DoSomeMoreIndependentWork();
    int i = await getInt;
    SomeStuffAfterTheAwait();
    return i;
}

public static void Main()
{
    Task.Run(async () => 
    {
        Task<int> getIntAsync = GetIntAsync();
        DoIndependentWork();
        int result = await getIntAsync;
        Console.WriteLine(result);          
    }).Wait();
}
```

and want to understand it in terms of the graph from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean).

Here's what I think is a possible flow of execution if `DoIndependentWork` and `DoSomeMoreIndependentWork` take a long time to execute:

```
|<--Launch GetInt-->||<-- DoSomeMoreIndependentWork-->||<-- DoIndependentWork -->||<-- Wait for GetInt to finish -->||<-- SomeStuffAfterTheAwait -->||<-- Console.WriteLine(result) -->|

                     |<------ Do GetInt .................................................................... ------>|
```

Is that correct? If not, what is a better representation of some or all of the possible flows of execution?

Comment: Where is the code for `GetInt`? `await` doesn't make anything run asynchronously, it awaits already asynchronous operations. Unless there is some real asynchronous code in there, that's just a blocking method. In which case, *all* methods execute sequentially